# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when assigning char to char pointer

Tags: c, pointers

this one should be an easy one..
I have the following code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    printf("Got to 1\n");
    char *str;
    *str='a';
    printf("*str contains: %c",*str);
}
```

I don't get the line "Got to 1" printed before I see the Segmentation Fault (core dumped) error.
Could anyone explain the reason behind this error?

Comment: The pointer doesn't point to anything so you are assigning a value to a random place in memory.

Comment: It will surely print "Got to 1" on screen.

Comment: @ani It might or might not.  Output is buffered and the crash may stop the buffer from being flushed properly.

Comment: @Ani, If any part is undefined behaviour, all bets are off. Undefined behaviour includes [time travel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx). And [optimizations](http://markshroyer.com/2012/06/c-both-true-and-false/).

Comment: OP is using `\n` so it will definitely print "Got to 1" on screen.

Comment: you're not assigning char to char pointer.  you're assigning char to an unknown memory location.

Comment: In short: all variables must be initialized before using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to allocate memory where you are going to store a character. The code can look like

```
char *str = malloc( sizeof( char ) );
*str='a';
printf("*str contains: %c\n",*str);
free( str );
```

Or you could write

```
char c;
char *str = &c;
*str='a';
printf("*str contains: %c\n",*str);
```

Also there is no need to include header `<string.h>` because neither declaration from the header is used in your program.

Answer (score 2):

`char *str;` just declare `str` as a pointer to `char`. It doesn't allocate memory. You need to allocate memory for `str` before assigning `'a'` to `*str`.

***Never apply an indirection operator to an uninitialized pointer***. Doing so, invoke **undefined behavior**.

Note that, assigning a value to `*str` is dangerous here because it is uninitialized. If it points to a valid memory address then

```
*str = 'a';
```

will try to modify the data stored at that location.
If the location modified by this assignment belongs to program it may behave *erratically*. If it belongs to the operating system then the program will most likely *crash*.

Answer (score 0):

The file stream stdout is buffered, and is not written to the display right away.

Answer (score 0):

first allocate memory for `char *str` then assign value.

```
    char *str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    *str='a';
    printf("*str contains: %c\n",*str);
    free( str );
```